# How can I achieve this slanted div implementation with CSS

Tags: css

How can I achieve this with CSS? Please see the attached image.

[image]

Comment: why this question is off-topic ??

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to achieve this; you could simply [use a forward-slash as the content of a pseudo element](http://jsfiddle.net/1c0uzbgL/). This would give you support further back than options that use transformations/skewing.

```
<span>Item One</span><span>Item Two</span>
```

```
span:after {
    content: "/";
    font-size: 5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span:last-child:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Another method, as I alluded to in the previous paragraph, is to [skew a pseudo element](http://jsfiddle.net/mzcgqvz4/1/).

```
span::after {
    content: "";
    margin: 0 1em;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    width: .5em; height: 5em;
}

span:last-child::after {
    content: none;
}
```

It's important to note that when dealing with pseudo elements, keep in mind that Internet Explorer 8 supports them, but only with a single `:` prefix. It wasn't until Internet Explorer 9 that you could use them with `::`.

Comment: This is a very interesting way to 'visually' add a div using `:after` with fixed width and height and to rotate it. I learned a lot from your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `div` give its one side `border` and then use `-webkit-transform` to `rotate` it.

```
<div class="background">
</div>
<div><label>Some Text Here</label></div>
<div id="dv">
<label>Some Different Text Here</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background {
border-top: 3px solid #ccc;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 50px;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-20px)
 translateX(5px)
 rotate(330deg);
}
#dv
{
-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px) translateX(300px) rotate(-1deg);
}
```

Here's **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/71dczcrj/2/)**